# Using packages written by the other in Spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

So the package I'm trying to use is here:

`https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel`

and on that page is the spring bean configuration for that package.  I'm new to spring, and I don't understand how to actually write code that uses the bean.
The config looks like this:

```
@Bean
public PoiItemReader excelReader() {
    PoiItemReader reader = new PoiItemReader();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/path/to/your/excel/file"));
    reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper());
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public RowMapper rowMapper() {
    return new PassThroughRowMapper();
}
```

So if I have another class called reader somewhere, how do I use this bean configuration to get the lines from the excel file that PoiItemReader gets from `.setRowMapper()`?

The row mapper has a list of arrays that split the values in the excel rows, but I don't know how to get that list.

Do I call the excelReader() method?

PoiItemReader doesn't have any useful methods associated with it, so I don't think I'm supposed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet, it looks like you're using `@Configuration` on the class that declares your beans.

Using Java Configuration is one of the ways to define your beans so that spring will understand them and inject property at runtime.
An alternative way is using annotations like `@Service, @Component, @Controller` and so forth (an answer provided by maneesh)

So the first thing to understand in Spring is that there are many ways of configuration (there is also an old-way, using XML and Groovy based configuration).

Now when you write a spring application, usually you use Spring Beans from other Spring Beans.

So, if you configure bean A to have a reference on Bean B, Spring will inject it for you. Example:

```
public class A {
    private B b;
    public A(B b) {
       this.b = b;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
      b.foo();
    } 
}

public class B {
    public void foo() {...}
}
```

The "java config" way for defining these beans can look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public A a(B b) {
     return new A(b);
  }

  @Bean
  public B b() {
     return new B();
  }
}
```

In your example, you've used an alternative syntax for Configurations (line `reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper());`:

@Configuration
   public class MyConfiguration {

```
  @Bean
  public A a() {
     return new A(b());
  }

  @Bean
  public B B() {
     return new B();
  }
```

}

It looks like from A you just call a method that creates B. But it is not quite like that, in fact, spring is supposed to wrap your configuration in some kind of runtime proxy so that, for example, if you call `b()` many times (for many beans), it will always return the same instance, because B has a singleton scope. *All-in-all Configuration classes should be considered like a Java DSL to create beans and not a regular code*.

Now the last question to consider is where all this configuration gets started. The answer to this really depends on the environment you're running it. Usually, spring is already integrated into existing projects that run on-top of tomcat or other servers, or if it's a Spring Boot application it already provides "well known" integration ways. So you might just ask someone from your project (I assume it's not a homework or something) how does your application is integrated with spring, it's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare @Service or @Component over the class where you want to read file, and use @Autowired annotation to use PoiItemReader

```
@Service
public class SomeclassName {

    @Autowired
    private PoiItemReader excelReader;

    public void somemethod() {
    //do some reading stuff here using excelReader
    }
}
```

Comment: So the trouble I'm having is that all of the methods in PoiItemReader are either protected, or they are setters, so I can't actually do anything with the reader.  All the tutorials I can find stop at configuration, but I don't see any way to actually use my PoiItemReader object.  In the git hub repository there is a class called PoiSheet that seems useful that has public methods and one of the protected methods in PoiItemReader returns a sheet.  All I can think to try is edit the jar to make the method public and see if I can do something with that.

Comment: can you please have a look at https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-an-excel-file/

Comment: That's the tutorial I'm confused about.  It stops at return the item reader, but I don't know what to do with the returned item reader because there aren't any useful methods associated with it.